# Increasing video height and width in Blackberry player screen

Tags: blackberry, video

I am playing video in Blackberry,it plays well but i need to show the video in full screen mode.Now it plays video with spaces at top and bottom i have to play in full screen

For this i used methods

```
videoControl.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
_videoControl.setDisplaySize(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
```

But those are not working how can i solve this.

Comment: What BB OS version are you trying to run your app in?

Comment: i am testing on 9700 OS5

Comment: I have had issues getting fullscreen videocontrols in OS5.0 Please could you try the same app in os6.0 and os 7.0 . I bet you will find different results. In OS7.0 you will defenitly see a fullscreen video.

Comment: ok but is itnot possible on OS5?

Comment: i tested on 9700 OS6 also.its not working

Comment: it is not showing in full screen

Comment: I'm assuming the video is not set to the screen size?

Answer (score 1):

The video player can be incredibly fickle when it comes to what sizes it will display. From my testing, it seems that you have to hit one of the magic ratios (half size seemed to work pretty reliably) or it just won't show anything.

Rather than setting the size that would equal fullscreen as well as telling it to be fullscreen, you should probably use `VideoControl.setDisplayFullScreen()` without the `setDisplaySize()`

I have an answer about camera programming that might help [Black berry camera programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634312/black-berry-camera-programming/5635910#5635910)